# Sending complete packets in the sockets

Tags: java, sockets

I'm making a client-server based game but the server has sometimes a problem with sending the packets.

Each connected client to the server has its own instance (class name `Peer`). This instance has a `ByteBuffer` variable named `buffer`. The peer class is a Runnable, so each client has its own thread.

The server can send different types of packets to the client, the first byte of the packet is the 'opcode' so that the client knowns what packet it is. When the client knows the opcode, then it also knows the size of the packet.

On every tick in the `while-loop` in the thread of the Peer class, all packets in the ByteBuffer will be sended to the client. But sometimes there are half packets in the bytebuffer because another thread is putting bytes in it on the same time. Then the client reads the opcode but is missing bytes of the packet.

This is the code of the Peer class that is sending the bytes in the bytebuffer:

```
                ByteBuffer buffer = this.buffer.duplicate();
                this.buffer.clear();
                int size = buffer.position();
                buffer.flip();
                byte[] data = new byte[size];
                buffer.get(data);
                out.write(data);
```

How can I make sure that it sends the complete packets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the producer-consumer paradigm, with a Queue of ByteBuffer and a separate thread to  send the packets. 
Make sure every producer thread has its own ByteBuffer,  and each ByteBuffer is put in the queue only once complete.